# SQL - Optimize date calculation for large table

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Can this query below be optimized?

```sql
select
     max(date), sysdate - max(date)
 from
     table;
```

Query execution time ~5.7 seconds

I have another approach

```
select
    date, sysdate - date
from
    (select * from table order by date desc)
where
    rownum = 1;
```

Query execution ~7.9 seconds

In this particular case, table has around 17,000,000 entries.

Is there a more optimal way to rewrite this?

**Update**: Well, I tried the hint a few of you suggested in a database development, although with a smaller subset than the original (approximately 1,000,000 records). Without the index the queries runs slower than with the index.

The first query, without index: ~0.56 secs, with index: ~0.2 secs. The second query, without index: ~0.41 secs, with index: ~0.005 secs. (This surprised me, I thought the first query would run faster than the second, maybe it's more suitable for smaller set of records).

I suggested to DBA this solution and he will change the table structure to accommodate this, and then i will test it with the actual data. Thanks

Comment: Is `date` a field in the table?

Comment: This will always require a full-table scan, I don't see any way to optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there an index on the date column?

Comment: Indexing the column will let you find the max/min much more quickly

Comment: @joeygs Are you able to add an index, or are you in a very restricted environment?  There are other options to improve performance, but they're not worth exploring unless you can't create an index.

Comment: @jonearles i'm not able to add an index on production database, i'm checking the index workaround in a development database.. what are the other options if this doesn't work?

Comment: @joeygs I don't believe there's anything you can do to the SQL to improve the query.  Your options are pretty much indexing the date column or buying new hardware.  The index should more than suffice, though :)

Comment: You can try parallelism, compression, pctfree 0, materialized views, `alter table table_name shrink space`, function result cache, or query result cache.  Each has significant disadvantages, and may not even help much anyway.  Definitely use an index if you can.

Comment: @jonearles I see I now have a lot of new things to read about haha, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That query is simple enough that there's likely nothing that can be done to optimize it beyond adding an index on the date column. What database is this? And is sysdate another column of the table?

Comment: This is a oracle database, in PL/SQL, SYSDATE is a function which always returns the OS current datetime value

Comment: @joeygs:  try adding an index on `date` and check the timing of the same queries.

Comment: while i'm not able to add an index on production database, i'll test this solution in an development database but with a small subset of data, to check the performance